# Robot Framework test inside a QThread does not show variable values in log file

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, qthread

I am trying to run a Robot Framework test inside a QThread. However when I use the keyword `Log` to log a variable value, the value is not shown in the "log.html" file.

I created a minimum example with three files:

**run_this.py**

```
import robot
from execute_robot_from_qthread import RobotExec

def start_robot_in_thread():
    robot_execution_thread = RobotExec()
    robot_execution_thread.start()
    robot_execution_thread.wait()

def start_robot_here():
    robot.run("test.robot")

#Uncomment the function to test

#If you run this the messages will not appear?
#start_robot_in_thread()

#But they do if you run this?!
start_robot_here()
```

**execute_robot_from_qthread.py**

```
import robot
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

class RobotExec(QThread):
    def run(self):
        robot.run("test.robot")
```

**test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Test do_test
    ${test} =     Set Variable     1
    Log    ${test}    WARN
    Log    ${test}
```

Use the command `python3 run_this.py` to start it.
If we run the function `start_robot_here()`, in `run_this.py`, all works as expected. However if we run the function `start_robot_in_thread()` the log file only shows the value when it is assigned to the variable. The first image below show the desired output and the second shows the output when running it in the qthread.

[image: Working one]

[image: NotWorking]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this related? "Messages logged by non-main threads using the normal logging methods from programmatic logging APIs are silently ignored."
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#communication-when-using-threads

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

I noticed that the logs were shown correctly on another computer. The problem seems to be that the package manager in debian, which raspberry pi os is based on, installs python "3.7.3". By manually installing python 3.8.10 the logging works.

**Original answer:**

Threads seems to be the problem, workaround is to run it as a process instead.

[log details like "INFO" is missing when the test runs in FLask #2914](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2914)